# Is Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite) a non-blocking call and can be used to sleep indefinitely without blocking?

Tags: c#, task

I am using Cosmos DB Change Feed library to process documents from Change Feed.

```
var docObserverFactory = DocumentFeedObserverFactory.Create(myCollectionInfo);
await host.RegisterObserverFactoryAsync(docObserverFactory);
Console.WriteLine("Awaiting indefinitely...press Cancel to exit");

// I set the CancellationToken to true on Console.CancelKeyPress Event
await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);
await host.UnregisterObserversAsync();
```

In the above code, after registering the observer factory, I need to hold this thread for an indeterminate time. Hence I use Task.Delay with infinite timeout value.

Questions:

1. I wanted to know if it is right to use Task.Delay() in this way.
2. I am concerned Task.Delay() will block a thread internally in case of infinite timeout to monitor the cancellation token.

Basically, I want a non-blocking sleep call that waits indefinitely without blocking.

Comment: `Task.Delay()` keeps a task open but doesn't block any other operations if that's what you mean, unlike `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: I wtore an article about this: http://blog.rogatnev.net/2017/10/29/Sleep-well.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I need to hold this thread".  What is "holding" on a thread?

Comment: It is not wrong.  There is no thread, other than the one that keeps all timers ticking, you only pay for a Timer object.  Why you can't unregister directly instead of signaling the cancellation token is not terribly obvious.  I suppose to got suckered into this code because of the demand to use async to unregister.  Odd btw.  Do what works.

Comment: By the way cancelation token is not meant to cancel running task, it is more cancel scheduled task. It is kind a misleading concept.

Comment: @EricLippert I meant blocking that thread indeterminately.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right. There's no need of cancellation token. The unregistration happens on ChangeFeedEventHost object. This comment actually gave me an idea to make CHangeFeedEventHost part of the class and use it to unregister during the application shutdown. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It feels a bit strange to use Task.Delay for that (especially because the cancel, which is expected, causes a `CancellationException`) . I prefer to use `SemaphoreSlim` for Tasks like this.

```
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim blockUntilFinishedOrCancel = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

    //Wait
    await this.blockUntilFinishedOrCancel.WaitAsync():

    //No More Waiting
    this.blockUntilFinishedOrCancel.Release(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is alternative not exactly answer to the question.

You need to block the access to `host.UnregisterObserversAsync()` until some event occur right ?

You can use [Monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) to simulate something like [producer / consumer](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Producer-Consumer-inter-aeaa9578) scenario.

Your approach should also do the job, but it looks a bit hacky ... on the other side the producer / consumer may be an overkill for something simple. Play with the code and see what feels right for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers and comments, I realize understood it wrong by seeing the below code on Change Feed usage on the internet. Particularly misunderstood "Console.ReadLine" as blocking the thread and I need to do the same. But there is no need to block this thread to unregister it. It can be done by any other thread.

```
using (DocumentClient destClient = new DocumentClient(destCollInfo.Uri, destCollInfo.MasterKey))
{
    DocumentFeedObserverFactory docObserverFactory = new DocumentFeedObserverFactory(destClient, destCollInfo);

    ChangeFeedEventHost host = new ChangeFeedEventHost(hostName, documentCollectionLocation, leaseCollectionLocation, feedOptions, feedHostOptions);
    await host.RegisterObserverFactoryAsync(docObserverFactory);

    // This is where I thought I need to block this thread indeterminately.
    Console.WriteLine("Running... Press enter to stop.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    await host.UnregisterObserversAsync();
}
```

As an alternative, I can make the ChangeFeedEventHost part of my class and expose a method to unregister it. On the CancelKeyPress event, I can call that unregsiter method. This way I need not sleep/block a thread indeterminately.